# Execute server side code in html

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to fill an html select element from a database, the server I am trying to read from uses classic asp.

Here is my html:

```
<div  >    
    <select
        style="width:200px"
        multiple = "single"
        size = "20">
        <% 
            Dim objTempRs
            SET objTempRs= DBX.GetRS("Select * from Infolink_Subscribers_Export")                                                                                       
            Do Until objTempRs.EOF
        %>   
        <option value="<%=objTempRs("SubscriberID")%>"><%=objTempRs("ExportName")%></option>                                                                                   
        <%  objTempRs.MoveNext                                                                          
            Loop   
        %>                                                                                              
    </select>    
</div>
```

but it fails to retrieve the data, hence that I have tried this same server side code in a classic asp page and it worked, but I am trying to create an equivalent html page. What might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you asking why that code works in a file with a `.asp` file extension but doesn't work in one with a `.html` file extension?

Comment: yes, and what to change to make it work in html

Comment: The server. How is it supposed to know you've put ASP code inside the file? The file extension is how it normally tells.

Comment: You should also, really, have the language reference at the top of the document (`<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>`).

Answer (score 2):

**In IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003 Server (no longer supported)**

Website properties -> Home Directory -> Configuration -> Mapping tab -> use Change or Add button for Application extension with following info:
Extension .HTML
Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll

Also suggest to limit requests to GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE

[image]

After that IIS will handle .HTML file as .ASP files

**In IIS 7.5**

Select Website -> Handler Mappings -> Add Script Map

[image]